# Alternative for case when statement that is not mutually exclsuive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I've a question. My table is:

| Keyword | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| peanut butter cookies | 246000 |
| peanut butter falcon | 201000 |
| peanut butter | 110000 |
| peanut cookie recipe | 90500 |
| the peanut butter falcon | 90500 |
| butter blossoms | 74000 |
| peanut butter whiskey | 74000 |

My SQL query:

```
Select
Case when Keyword like '%peanut%' then 'peanut'
Case when Keyword like '%butter%' then 'butter'
Case when Keyword like '%falcon%' then 'falcon'
ELSE 'other' END as cluster,
count(Keyword) as count_Keyword
from tablename
group by cluster
```

My output

| Cluster | count_Keyword |
| --- | --- |
| peanut | 6 |
| butter | 1 |

I'm looking for a solution that's not mutually exclusive and returns the following:

| Cluster | count_Keyword |
| --- | --- |
| peanut | 6 |
| butter | 6 |
| Falcon | 2 |

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) Statements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `COUNT` with a `LIKE`?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%peanut%' THEN 1 END) AS Peanut,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%butter%' THEN 1 END) AS Butter,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%Falcon%' THEN 1 END) AS Falcon
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. My actual query would also include a few other selections such as sum(Volume)

`count(Keyword) as count_Keyword, sum(Volume) as Volume
from tablename
group by cluster`

Comment: You can add other aggregates, if you want, @wouterbuijze , this answers the question you've asked.

Comment: Ok, thanks again, sorry I'm quite a beginner. What would this look like? The following is not working for me..

`SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%peanut%' THEN 1 END) AS Peanut,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%butter%' THEN 1 END) AS Butter,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%Falcon%' THEN 1 END) AS Falcon,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%peanut%' THEN Volume END) AS Peanut_Volume,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%butter%' THEN Volume END) AS Butter_ Volume,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Keyword LIKE '%Falcon%' THEN Volume END) AS Falcon_ Volume
FROM dbo.YourTable;`

Comment: What does "not working" mean @wouterbuijze ?

Comment: Is it simply your typographical errors such as `AS Butter_ Volume` @wouterbuijze ? (Notice the space after the underscore.)

Comment: Sorry, I think I found the error, my bad! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the keyword patterns in a derived table and use `join`:

```
Select c.cluster, count(t.keyword)
from tablename t
     (select 'peanut' as cluster union all
      select 'butter' union all
      select 'falcon'
     ) c left join
     tablename t
     on t.keyword like concat('%', c.cluster, '%')
group by c.cluster;
```

Answer (score 0):

May this solve your problem?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859eae

```
create table dummy(
  Keyword varchar(255),
  Volumne int
);

insert into dummy
values
  ('peanut butter cookies', 246000),
  ('peanut butter falcon', 201000),
  ('peanut butter', 110000),
  ('peanut cookie recipe', 90500),
  ('the peanut butter falcon', 90500),
  ('butter blossoms', 74000),
  ('peanut butter whiskey', 74000);

select
  c.cluster, count(t.Keyword) as cnt
from
  (
      select 'peanut' as cluster union all
      select 'butter'            union all
      select 'falcon'
  ) c
    left join dummy t
    on t.Keyword like concat('%', c.cluster, '%')
group by c.cluster;
```